# Set Axis label to integer format. Devexpress chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, devexpress

I am using bar chart. I need to have labels in integer format.

I am using this code

```
<dxc:AxisY2D.NumericOptions>
      <dxc:NumericOptions Precision="0" Format="Number" />
</dxc:AxisY2D.NumericOptions>
```

Then I get range values from 0 to 1 like 0 0 0 1 1 1. When I set GridSpacing to 1. It solves the problem. But for large amount of data the view with GridSpacing = 1 is ridiculous.

I need to have the label in integer format for small and large amount of data.